# Python/Numpy/Boolean Indexing: For each True value in array, modify the next 2 elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-indexing

I have a numpy array

```
array = np.array([5,100,100,100,5,5,100,100,100,5])
```

I create a mask with boolean indexing like so:

```
mask = (array < 30)
```

This gives a mask like

```
[ True False False False  True  True False False False  True]
```

I can get the indices of the `True` values in the mask with

```
indices = np.where(mask)[0]
```

This gives

```
[0 4 5 9]
```

For every `True` value in the mask, I would like to modify the next 2 elements to also be `True`.

I can do this with a `for` loop like so:

```
for i in indices:
    mask[i:i+3] = True
```

Is there a more numpythonic approach to this without using a `for` loop?

Desired mask output:

```
[ True  True  True False  True  True  True  True False  True]
```

The main priority here is performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.flatnonzero` to simplify the getting of indices. Then you can add `np.arange(3)` to each one:

```
ind = np.flatnonzero(mask)[:, None] + np.arange(3)
```

The only caveat is that your index may contain a couple of out-of-bounds elements. You can trim them with a mask or `np.clip`:

```
ind[ind >= mask.size] = mask.size - 1
```

You can then apply the index directly, since numpy allows arbitrary dimensions for fancy indices:

```
mask[ind] = True
```

If you have a small smear to do, you can smear the mask directly:

```
mask[1:] |= mask[:-1]
mask[1:] |= mask[:-1]
```

You'll obviously have to put this in a loop if the smear amount is arbitrary, but you can optimize it by stepping in powers of two.

I call the operation `mask[1:] |= mask[:-1]` smearing because it expands the size of any group of `True` elements to the right by one, as if you smeared the ink with your finger. To smear an arbitrary amount `n`:

```
s = 1
while s <= n:
    mask[s:] |= mask[:-s]
    s *= 2
s = n - s // 2
if s:
    mask[s:] |= mask[:-s]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm getting a "IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10" on the "mask[ind] = True" line

Comment: Right. I forgot about that. Hang on

Comment: @CraigNathan. Fixed. Use the second option (mask smear)

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind explaining what smearing is and how I might set up a loop for it? What would I use as my iterator?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Thanks! Marking this as the answer, but ideally I would like to avoid using a for loop if you have any suggestions for that. This is an example array, my project has a much larger dataset and takes hours to run when using the full dataset so I'm trying to shave off time everywhere I can.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @CraigNathan. If you have a small amount of smear, you can hard code it, no loop necessary. If it's not so small, use the indexing approach. It's more memory intensive, but very very fast

Comment: Great, thank you. Can you explain what adding np.arange(3) does? If I take it out it doesn't seem to affect the output.

Do I even need to keep track of the indices since the smearing doesn't use them?

Comment: @CraigNathan. If you inspect the result of that statement, you'll see immediately. It adds a second dimension that contains `i`, `i+1`, `i+2` for each index `i`. The reason I break the code into bits like that is so that you have an easier time inspecting and playing with them.

Comment: Thank you for your help!